# Having an issue with Flask, SQLlite3, SQLAcedemy, and SQL and unique column constraints and Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having a problem with SQLite3 and unique column constraints here are my python model for a user.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="author", lazy=True)
```

When I create a new user:

```
user=User(username="ginger", email="ginger@gmail.com", password="ginger")
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

I receive a the following error:

```
`enter code here`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.username
```

However the database is completely empty.  I'm really confused as to how to resolve this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Answer (score 0):

I am so new to python that I feel like an idiot. I recently restructured my code and was using a relative path to the database.  So I actually had two databases in two separate folders. The one I had open in the SQLite browser was empty however my application was inserting into the other database and yes the data I was inserting was a duplicate of what was already there.

Thanks
Dawson